# ISA-specific Assembly instructions description

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, assembly, doxygen

I have been wondering if it would be possible to create a description for each Assembly instruction which would pop-up when you hoover over the instruction with a mouse in an IDE. Just like when you create a @brief description of your c-function in it's function prototype in .h file.

In a pseudo C style, the @brief of AND "function" could look like this.

```
/**@{*/
/**
 * @brief   AND - Bitwise Logical And
 * Assembler Syntax     AND ar, as, at
 * @param ar - result
 * @param as - ...
 * @param at - ...
 * AND calculates the bitwise logical and of address registers as and at. The result is
 *  written to address register ar.
 */
and(ar, as, at);
```

To create this @briefs for each instruciton and then include the library into my project.
I am working with multiple custom ISAs with different instructions. So I don't have to go to ISA.pdf to search each instruction every time. I am not sure, if the mouse hoovering is being taken care of by an IDE (VSCode in my case), or by Doxygen or something else.

Comment: Visual Studio Code offers syntax highlighting extensions like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=13xforever.language-x86-64-assembly).